# Aggregating a huge list from reducer input without running out of memory

Tags: list, hadoop, memory, collections, mapreduce

At the reduce stage (67% of reduce percentage), my code ends up getting stuck and failing after hours of attempting to complete. I found out that the issue is that the reducer is receiving huge amounts of data that it can't handle and ends up running out of memory, which leads to the reducer being stuck.

Now, I am trying to find a way around this. Currently, I am assembling a list from the values received by the reducer fro each key. At the end of the reduce phase, I try to write the key and all of the values in the list. So my question is, how can I get the same functionality of having the key and list of values related to that key without running out of memory?

```
public class XMLReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, TextArrayWritable> {
private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(XMLReducer.class);

@Override
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    //logger.info(key.toString());
    Set<String> filesFinal = new HashSet<>();
    int size = 0;
    for(Text value : values) {
        String[] files = value.toString().split(",\\s+");
        filesFinal.add(value.toString());
        //size++;
    }
    //logger.info(Integer.toString(size));
    String[] temp = new String[filesFinal.size()];
    temp = filesFinal.toArray(temp);
    Text[] tempText = new Text[filesFinal.size()];
    for(int i = 0; i < filesFinal.size(); i++) {
        tempText[i] = new Text(temp[i]);
    }               
}
}
```

and TextArrayWritable is just a way to write an array to file

Answer (score 0):

You can try reducing the amount of data that is read by the single reducer by writing a Custom partitioner.

**HashPartitioner** is the default partitioner that is used by the map reduce job. While this guarantees you uniform distribution, in some cases it is highly possible that many keys get hashed to a single reducer. As a result, a single reducer would have a lot of data compared to others. In your case, I think this is the issue.

To resolve this:

1. Analyze your data and the key on which you are doing group by. You
2. Try to come up with a partitioning function based on your group by key for your Custom Partitioner. Try limiting the number of keys for each partition.

You would see an increase in number of reduce tasks in your job. If the issue is related to uneven key distribution, the solution that I proposed  should resolve your issue.

You could also try increasing reducer memory.

Comment: Sorry, have been occupied with other issue that I didn't check stackoverflow in a couple of days. This did not solve my issue as I was getting too much data per key. This means that a partitioner would not fix this issue. I tried to implement a custom streaming output format which solves the issue of having to store the values in memory. As of now though, I'm not quite sure how to eliminate duplicates in my output